# Correct use of cos() and sin() in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert, just for fun, a code listing written in a language called Seed7 into Python. I've got it just about to beta phase, except for one part. This is the extract of the Seed7 listing:

```
x1 := flt(column) + 0.5;
y1 := flt(row) + 0.5;
angle := (course - 1.0) * 0.785398;
delta_x := cos(angle);
delta_y := -sin(angle);
inquad := TRUE;
blocked := FALSE;
number := 1;
while number <= distance do
  y1 := y1 + delta_y;
  x1 := x1 + delta_x;
  row := trunc(y1);
  column := trunc(x1);
  if column < 1 or column > 8 or row < 1 or row > 8 then
     inquad := FALSE;
     number := distance;
  else
    if sect[row][column] <> 1 then  (* Object blocking move *)
       blocked := TRUE;
       number := distance;
    end if;
  end if;
  incr(number);
end while;
```

Which all makes sense, except for the fact that I don't understand how the functions cos() and sin() work in Seed7.

The manual says:

sin

const func float: sin (in float: x)

```
Compute the sine of x, where x is given in radians.

Returns:
    the trigonometric sine of an angle.
```

but I can't make the equivalent in Python.

This problem is purely one caused by me not understanding Python properly (and not really being that great with maths either), so I come here to ask someone who does understand these things.

What code is required to make the above code work in Python? Help!!! :-)

Many thanks,

Joseph.

Edit: I think the problem is the incr() function. Basically, it is possible to warp in this game less than 1. From the help files:

```
writeln("Warp - One warp moves you the width of a quadrant.  A warp of .5 will move you");
    writeln("halfway through a quadrant.  Moving diagonally across a quadrant to the next");
    writeln("will require 1.414 warps.  Warp 3 will move you 3 quadrants providing nothing");
    writeln("in your present quadrant blocks your exit.  Once you leave the quadrant that");
    writeln("you were in, you will enter hyperspace; coming out of hyperspace will place you");
    writeln("randomly in the new quadrant.  Klingons in a given quadrant will fire at you");
    writeln("whenever you leave, enter, or move within the quadrant.  Entering a course or");
    writeln("warp of zero can be used to return to the command mode.")
```

My code looks like this:

```
x1 = float(column) + 0.5
    y1 = float(row) + 0.5
    angle = (course - 1.0) * 0.785398
    deltaX = math.cos(angle)
    deltaY = -math.sin(angle)

    inQuad = True
    blocked = False
    num = 1
    while num <= distance:
        y1 += deltaY
        x1 += deltaX
        row = int(round(y1))
        column = int(round(x1))
        if column < 0 or column > 7 or row < 0 or row > 7:
            inQuad = False
            num = distance
        else:
            if sect[row][column] != 1:
                blocked = True
                num = distance

        num += 1
```

The thing is I'm using num+=1 at the end there, as opposed to incr, but I don't understand incr. As I have said, I've been a bit long out of the game, and certain things are really catching me out.

Any help in shining a light would be appreciated.

Joseph.

Comment: Please shorten post down to post just your question, a whole story is not needed as it's just fluff and not useful to anyone. What's the problem you're having? Is `math.cos` and `math.sin` not working? Did you read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)?

Comment: Andrew - Post shortened. The only reason I did it that way was I have often not added enough info in what questions I have asked previously, and I didn't want people barracking me for being a n00b when - well - I am... ;) In answer to your question, I just put the functions in, and all hell broke loose. The link you provided me in theory says it should just work, but it's not. I'll go back and recheck my code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A guess:

If Seed7 expects radians, you may need to convert degrees to radians before applying sin or cos:

```
import math
math.sin(math.radians(1))
```